# Encapsulate JQuery Confirm into a function

Tags: jquery, confirm

The code below is the sample Jquery Confirm

```
$.confirm({
    title: 'Confirm!',
    content: 'Simple confirm!',
    buttons: {
        confirm: function () {
            return true;
        },
        cancel: function () {
            return false
        }
    }
});
```

This code looks good and it also make me eliminate the JS Confirm. However this code is too many and in-appropriate if all my button has that so I decided to make a function that will call it like this..

```
function CustomConfirm (message) {
   /* the JS Confirm above */
}
```

then I will call it just like this

```
if (CustomConfirm("Are you sure you want to delete?") == true) {
  /* true */
} else {
  /* false */
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given how the [`$.confirm`](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/#confirm) library works you cannot call it in an `if` condition in the manner you suggest.

It requires the callback functions for each button to be provided to the settings object when the library is instantiated. In your example it would look like this:

```js
function CustomConfirm(message, confirmCallback, cancelCallback) {
  $.confirm({
    title: 'Confirm!',
    content: message,
    buttons: {
      confirm: confirmCallback,
      cancel: cancelCallback
    }
  });
});

CustomConfirm("Are you sure you want to delete?", () => {
  console.log('confirmed...');
}, () => {
  console.log('cancelled...');
})
```